# Can you make the border transparent?

Tags: css, html

In CSS is there a way to make the border transparent, but the box (inside) with the border the same?

Please see this link:
http://jsfiddle.net/xiiJaMiiE/LfWBn/14/

```
#white_box {
position:absolute;
min-width:90%;
max-width:90%;
margin:0 auto;
height:92%;
top:0%;
left:5%;
right:5%;
background:white;
z-index:1;
width:80%;
border:5px #0F0 solid;
}
```

I would like to know if I can make the green border 0.6 opacity and keep the white inside normal.

Is that possible or would I have to make 2 divs on top each other?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use: `border: 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.6) solid;`

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y78Ap/)

```
#white_box {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 92%;
    top: 0%;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    background: white;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 80%;
    border: 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.6) solid;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `outline` too; both have different results.

```
outline: 10px solid rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.6);
```

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y24PF/)

Answer (score 0):

Here if you want fully transparent than, you can use [`border-color: transparent`](http://www.researchkitchen.de/blog/archives/css-bordercolor-transparent.php)-

```
border: 5px solid transparent;
```

[Try in fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/LfWBn/16/)

```
Unfortunately, in Explorer, border-color: transparent is rendered as black.
```

Or if you you only want partially-transparent border, than you can use `rgb with alpha transparency`-

```
border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); // 0.5 means 50% of opacity
```

The alpha transparency variate between 0 (0% opacity = 100% transparent) and 1 (100 opacity = 0% transparent)

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LfWBn/17/)

Answer (score 0):

this answer to add some info only. (3 ways : `box-shadow:outset x x x ;` or `box-shadow: inset  x x x;` , or `background-clip` )

if you want **opacity on borders and see through background of parent** container, and not mixe with the background of the element itself, you can draw the background-color with inset shadow. http://jsfiddle.net/Y78Ap/1/ (increased voluntary border-width and added a gradient to body to have it more 'telling')

```
html,body {
 Background-color:rgba(255,165,0,0.5);
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.3), rgba(255,255,255,0.3));
 }

#white_box {
    position:absolute;
    min-width:90%;
    max-width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:92%;
    top:0%;
    left:5%;
    right:5%;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2000px white;
    z-index:1;
    width:80%;
    border: 15px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.6) solid;
}
```

You can as well just draw borders with `box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,255,0,0.6);` instead border

The easiest way suppose to be, nowdays,  is background-clip : http://css-tricks.com/transparent-borders-with-background-clip/